# What are the advantages/disadvantages of marking function IsMacroType in Excel-DNA?

Tags: excel-dna

A number of calls into Excel's XLL API are only permitted by Excel-DNA if the function's `ExcelFunction` attribute specifies `IsMacroType=true`. What I'm unclear of is why simply adding this to all of my functions and being done with it is not a good idea; I'm assuming it is not otherwise it would be the default.

Something to do with volatility of function calculation by Excel itself? If there is a good resource online describing the pros and cons of `IsMacroType=true` I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `IsMacroType=true` attribute changes the parameters Excel-DNA uses when registering the function, which is done with a call to `xlfRegister`, as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687900.aspx In particular, Excel-DNA adds a "#" to the end of the `pxTypeText` parameter.

The documentation says:

> Placing a # character after the last parameter code in `pxTypeText`
>   gives the function the same calling permissions as functions on a
>   macro sheet. These are as follows:
>
> - The function can retrieve the values of cells that have not yet been calculated in this recalculation cycle.
> - The function can call any of the XLM information (Class 2) functions, for example, `xlfGetCell`.
>
> If the number sign (#) is not present:
>
> - evaluating an uncalculated cell results in an `xlretUncalced` error, and the current function is
>     called again once the cell has been calculated;
> - calling any XLM
>     information function other than `xlfCaller` results in an `xlretInvXlfn`
>     error.

Some disadvantages of marking a function as `IsMacroType=true`:

- they cannot be multi-threaded - Excel-DNA will not add the "$" suffix when registering, even if they are marked as `IsThreadSafe=true`.
- if they contain at least one parameter of type `object` that is marked `[ExcelArgument(AllowReference=true)]` then the function is automatically considered as volatile by Excel (even if the function is explicitly marked as `IsVolatile=false`.)

Further, my understanding is that such functions are treated differently in the dependency processing during Excel calculations. So you might expect some changes on the order in which sheets calculate. I have no reference or reproduction for this, though.

My recommendation is to only set `IsMacroType=true` in exceptional cases, when you know it is certainly required and you are prepared to investigate any issues that might arise.